# Cannot read post parameters with Node.js and Express framework

Tags: node.js, express

I have a node.js server with express Framework.

```
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var api_helper = require('./helpers/api_helper');
var app = express();

app.use(app.router);
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 8081);

app.post('/api/nodev1/users/login', function(req, res){
  var email = req.param('email', null);
  var password = req.param('password', null);
  console.log(email);console.log(password);
});

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

When I try to post a request to /api/nodev1/users/login I cannot read the parameters. I am trying with curl as follows:

```
curl -d "email=user@example2.com" -d "password=mypassword" http://localhost:8081/api/nodev1/users/login
```

The email and password are undefined.

Comment: You have a typo in there.  Line 12 should be `var password = req.param('password', null);`

Comment: thanks for the typo Joe. Fixed. It still doesn't solve my problem :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to move `app.use(app.router)` below `app.use(express.bodyParser())`. `app.router` is just a hook in which stage to handle your routes. And if it comes before `bodyParser` the body is not parsed.

Your code could look like this (in case I didn't manage to explain understandable):

```
var app = express();

app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 8081);

app.use(app.router);

// I added following line so you can better see what happens
app.use(express.logger('dev'));

app.post('/api/nodev1/users/login', function(req, res){ ... }
```

*Offtopic remark*: `express.bodyParser()` should only be used when you have file-uploads. And then you have to take care of deleting temp-files. If you don't have file-uploads, you are better off with only

```
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded());
```

I just wanted to add this in case you didn't know. I ran in problems because I didn't know...

**Edit for Express 4**

Thanks to @jonathan-ong there is no `app.use(app.router)` since Express 4:

> All routing methods will be added in the order in which they appear. You should **not** do `app.use(app.router)`. This eliminates the most common issue with Express.
>
> In other words, mixing `app.use()` and `app[VERB]()` will work **exactly** in the order in which they are called.

[Read more: New features in 4.x](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/wiki/New-features-in-4.x).

Comment: I don't want the parameters to be passed through the url, I want them on the body of the request

Comment: It is the body. You should see that the URL is only ...login in your Express-log.

Comment: How do you want to post the values? Is it a HTML form? Or should it be a REST api and you want to send JSON?

Comment: hgoebl, it will be used by a client side application that will make a post to that URL, and it sends the parameters in the body. I did the change that you told me in the curl and still no luck

Comment: I didn't know about your offtopic remark. Thanks. But I am still not able to get email and password from my request :(

Comment: Ok, You found the error: app.router is just a hook in which stage to handle your routes. And if it comes before bodyParser the body is not parsed. Thanks!

Comment: as of express 4, app.use(app.router) is removed. please see the docs https://github.com/visionmedia/express/wiki/New-features-in-4.x

Answer (score 0):

*edit* - nope, see other answer about middleware order!

---

change `req.param` to `req.body.x`:

```
app.post('/api/nodev1/users/login', function(req, res){
  var email = req.param('email', null);
  var password = req.param('password', null);
  console.log(email);console.log(password);
});
```

to

```
app.post('/api/nodev1/users/login', function(req, res){
  var email = req.body.email);
  var password = req.body.password);
  console.log(email); console.log(password);
});
```

Comment: It's the same thing. The function `param` looks in `req.params`, `req.body`, and `req.query` in that order. [Source](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/master/lib/request.js#L286)

Comment: ok thanks. do note that the linked source says on [line 276](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/master/lib/request.js#L276) that `req.body` must be an object. it may not be an object without `app.use(express.bodyParser())`